# How do I select a random checkbox on the web page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have 3 checkboxes on the webpage. Each time, I want to select checkboxes randomly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use findElements to have a list of checkboxes then you simply have to pick a random element:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".myCheckboxClass"));

WebElement randomCheckbox = checkboxes.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
```

Note: It assumes some element will be found by the locator - if no element is found, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method code:

```
public void clickonRandomCheckBox()
{
    List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    Random ram=new random.nextInt(1,3);
    if(!checkboxes.get(ram).isSelected)
    {
        checkboxes.get(ram).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 - It is not valid Java code. 2 - The code does not "click on a random checkbox", it "UNSELECTS a random checkbox IF IT IS SELECTED, otherwise, it DOES NOTHING"

Comment: first of all it's a valid code .Please check your knowledge level isSelected() return true if checkbox is selected else its return false i have apply the not operation here .Go and Do the RnD

Comment: Although the reply was quite unfriendly (already reported), I will point out the errors: "new random" is not syntacticly correct; "new Random()" would be the case. Random.nextInt returns an int, not a Random.

Comment: Additionally, as you said, the code, when corrected would result in a NoOP if the randomly choosen is already selected. The question is asking how to select a checkbox. Not selecting anything is not, by definition, selecting something. The code implies additional behavior not asked on the question.

Comment: Both of you need to calm down. You are both right, and both wrong. In Java and C#, you need to call `new Random()`. In Java, you would need to use `nextInt(3)` to correctly choose a random integer to select one of the checkboxes. In C#, the equivalent is `Next(3)`. You could also use `Next(0, 3)`. Both of you have missed that Java uses 0-based indexing, so as soon as the random generator returns 3, the code will throw an index out of bounds exception. The question asks how to select, so if something is already selected, it is selected and needs no more action. Viven, you could update (...cont)

Comment: to explain why you believe your code will help the OP. @JoãoFarias, you originally missed the negation that aims to ensure that any checkbox already selected is not unchecked by the code. Your initial comment with the caps lock is also not terribly friendly. You would have been better editing the post for syntax correctness and adding a comment to explain your edits. Please remember that the goal is not to prove anyone right or wrong. It's to provide the best possible content on this site (yes, I have made some mistakes here. Some of them massive errors).